# Node.Js не видит модули

Tags: node.js

Проблема в следующем: 
Подключил модуль express через консоль, при запуске приложения выдаёт ошибку.

```
// получаем модуль Express
const express = require('express')
// создаем приложение
const app = express()

// устанавливаем обработчик для маршрута "/"
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.end('Hello from Express!')
})
// начинаем прослушивание подключений на 3000 порту
app.listen(3000)
```

Вот код программы.

[image: Вот такую ошибку выдаёт.]
[image: Вот расположение модулей.]

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить модуль и (или) очистить кэш.

Comment: Пробовал. Результат тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты ноду запускаешь неправильно, она ищет модули в папке проекта, не в папке юзера `C:\Users\parku\` (где у тебя модули установлены)

Для того, чтобы запустить ноду в папке с проектом, нужно в cmd\powershell перейти по пути проекта, а лучше следовать следующим шагам:

1. Открой папку с проектом
2. Кликни по пустому месту (убери селект с файлов)
3. Зажми shift и по пустом месту кликни ПКМ
4. В контекстном меню выбери: "Открыть окно (powershell\cmd) здесь"
5. Дальше уже можешь можешь запускать проект с этой консольки

И еще, именно так(через эту консоль) нужно устанавливать модули\пакеты

Btw, это должна твоя ide'шка делать, в крайнем случае .bat файл содержащий: `node pro.js` (либо `npm run command`, команда из `package.json`)

Comment: Благодарю.Сильно помог.